# PHP Form Validation assistant

Tags: php, forms, validation, mysqli

I really need a help. I know there are similar help with my, but have tried them out no luck.

Am creating a Registration system with user type using PHP and Mysqli procedural. Am just starting up with PHP so please bear with me.

I need help with form validation... it looks OK to me, but the error is not processing. Below is my register and errMsg code.

Connection Code:

```
    define('HOST','localhost');
    define('USERNAME','');
    define('PASSWORD','');
    define('DBNAME','');
    $con=mysqli_connect(HOST,USERNAME,PASSWORD,DBNAME)or die('ERROR WHILE CONNECTING TO DATABASE SERVER');
    ?>
```

Registration and errMsg code

```
    <?php
    session_start(); 
    if(is_file('include/connection.php'))
    include_once('include/connection.php');
    else
    exit('Database FILES MISSING:(');
    ?>
    <?php $_SESSION['main_title']  = "Registration Page"; ?>
    <?php
    if(isset($_SESSION['user_type'])){
      header('Location: index.php');
    }

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
      extract($_POST);

    // $name = $_POST["name"];
    // $email = $_POST["email"];
    // $password = $_POST["password"];

    // $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $name);
    // $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $email);
    // $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $password);


          $created_at = date('Y-m-d');
          $queryInsert = "insert into user (name,last_name,user_name,user_type,email,password,created_at) values ('$name','$last_name','$user_name','$user_type','$email','$password','$created_at')";
          $resInsert = mysqli_query($con,$queryInsert);
            if($resInsert){

                $_SESSION['main_notice'] = "Successfully registered, login here!";
                header('Location: index.php');

            }else{
                $_SESSION['main_notice'] = "Some error, try again";
                header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
            }
          }

    ?>
    <?php 
    if(is_file('include/header.php'))
    include_once('include/header.php');
    ?>
    <?php
             // define variables and set to empty values
             $nameErr = $lnameErr = $userErr = "";
             $name = $lname = $user = "";

             if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
               // validate first name
                if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
                   $nameErr = "first Name is required";
                }else {
                   $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
                }
               // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
                      if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
                        $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
                      }

               // validate last name
               if (empty($_POST["lname"])) {
                   $lnameErr = "Last Name is required";
                }else {
                   $lname = test_input($_POST["lname"]);
                }
               // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
                      if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$lname)) {
                        $lnameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
                      }

               // validate user type
               if (empty($_POST["user_name"])) {
                   $userErr = "Last Name is required";
                }else {
                   $user = test_input($_POST["user_name"]);
                }
               // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
                      if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$user)) {
                        $userErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
                      }

             }//end validate tag

        ?>

    <div>

      <form name="register" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" onsubmit="return check()">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>Name</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="name" value='<?php echo $name ?>'><span style='color: red'>* <?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
    </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Last Name</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="last_name" value='<?php echo $lname ?>'><span style='color: red'>* <?php echo $lnameErr;?></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>User Name</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="user_name" value='<?php echo $user ?>'><span style='color: red'>* <?php echo $userErr;?></span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>User Type</td>
          <td>
          <select name="user_type" >
            <option value="member">Member</option>
            <option value="leader">Leader</option>
          </select>
          </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
          <td>Email</td>
          <td><input type="email" name="email" ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Password:</td>
          <td><input type="password" name="password" id="password" ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Confirm Password:</td>
          <td><input type="password" name="confirm_password" id="confirm_password" ></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Register"></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      </form>   
    </div>
    <script>

             function test_input($data) {
                $data = trim($data);
                $data = stripslashes($data);
                $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
                return $data;
             }
    // function check(){
    //  if(document.getElementById('password').value != document.getElementById('confirm_password').value ){
    //      alert('password not match');
    //      return false;
    //  }else{
    //      return true;
    //  }
    // }
    </script> 
    <?php
    if(is_file('include/footer.php'))
    include_once('include/footer.php');
    ?>
```

Am not sure if am missing something, but when i send the form without any input, it process it on database. And if i put input in just name field, it just refresh and go blank, even the value data doesn't work idea.

I hope have given enough information for your help, please if any question do ask me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The order of your code seems like it **may** be the issue. You are checking if the `$_POST['submit']` is set and then performing your database operations before the section of code which carries out validation. The section which sets the values to empty should come first, the you want to check if `$_POST['submit']` is set, and if it is you THEN do the validation within the if statement. So quickly in pseudocode:

```
include PHP files
check if user is already logged in
initialise variables
if submit is set {
    Validate the input
    if valid {
        Submit to database
    } else {
        return error messages as needed
    }
}
```

I hope this helps

EDIT:

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO user (name, last_name, user_name, user_type, email, password, created_at) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$stmt->bind_param("sssssss", $name, $last_name, $user_name, $user_type, $email, $password, $created_at);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->close();
$con->close();
```

Also, noticed a few more issues with your other code which may cause you problems.

1. In the input checks, you are setting variables like `$nameErr` if the field is invalid. Once you've sorted the code order out though you may find that you have to introduce a check for whether or not you actually have an error at the end of the validation or it will attempt to execute the database section anyway.
2. The error variables are echo'd to the page but if the all the inputs were acceptable, none of these variables will be defined and PHP might throw errors

Reorganise the code, and then have a careful look at it and think about how the data flow would work when valid and invalid (or null) input is provided.

Comment: As a sidenote, if you're just getting into PHP have a look at using prepared statements for MySQL instead of the way you're doing it there. Your way works, but you have a greater risk of SQL injection attacks unless you are very thorough with your input validation - http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Comment: Thanks for the input... I can go further with the form input by protecting it. But I think have tried your suggestion before as well. Can kindly edit my code to reflect this. So I can compare to what have done before. Pls I will appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: Thank so much I will look into this and if any issue I will seek help. Thanks for your time and I input.